# Can I get the suffix of a file from tf.train.string_input_producer()?

Tags: tensorflow

There isn't a general function that allows you to automatically identify if an image is jpeg or png in TensorFlow. The code will break if it receives an invalid input.

I would like to populate a string_input_producer with lots of filenames (jpeg and png included), then evaluate the suffixes before deciding to pipe it to decode_jpeg or decode_png.

Can someone provide a way to do this without doing any preprocessing?

**EDIT** @Allen

Code to illustrate what I am doing.

```
def inputs():
    filenames = get_filenames() # crawls directories for all jpeg and png files.
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    image = read_image(filename_queue) # this function has to split between decode_jpeg and decode_png
    image = preprocess(image)
    ...shuffle_batch stuff...
    return batch

def train():
    input = inputs()
    predictions = inference(input)
    ...loss definition and standard stuff...
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    sess.run([train_op])
```

This is what I intend to do. I don't think it's possible to do an eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#cond) seems like what you're looking for (just make sure the image processing ops are defined inside fn1 and fn2 so you get true conditional execution), in combination with [tf.decode_raw](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_raw) to read off the last few bytes of the filename:

```
tf.decode_raw(string, tf.uint8)
```

The result is a vector of integers containing bytes from the string, which can be sliced and compared using TensorFlow ops. For example, to check if a string ends in ".jpeg":

```
import tensorflow as tf

def is_jpeg(file_name_string):
    file_name_bytes = tf.decode_raw(file_name_string, tf.uint8)
    return tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(file_name_bytes[-5:],
                                  tf.decode_raw(".jpeg", tf.uint8)))

with tf.Session():
    print(is_jpeg(tf.convert_to_tensor("file1.png")).eval()) # false
    print(is_jpeg(tf.convert_to_tensor("file2.jpeg")).eval()) # true
```

To finish this up with image decoding, pass the resulting boolean Tensor as the predicate to cond():

```
decoded_image = tf.cond(is_jpeg(file_name),
                        lambda: read_and_decode_jpeg(file_name),
                        lambda: read_and_decode_png(file_name))
```

Comment: tf.decode_raw(bytes, out_type, little_endian=None, name=None) does not allow out_type to be a string.

Comment: Sorry, my omission. tf.decode_raw("abc", tf.uint8) works; the output is an array of bytes.

Comment: So you're proposing to compare the bytes? This means that I need to know the bytes of a string '.jpeg'.

Comment: I've edited in an example of using decode_raw to compare. Does that clarify?

Comment: I've edited some code to illustrate what I am doing. Your method works if you can call an eval, but I don't think I can do that.

Comment: The eval()s were just to illustrate the result of the is_jpeg function. is_jpeg itself operates purely on Tensors. I've edited in a sketch of where I think it would be used inside your read_image function.

Comment: Ah, perfect! This looks like it would work. The TF team might wanna consider this functionality added. There's been an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4009) on this already.